# AutoBogus AutoFaker custom generator

Tags: c#, test-data, autobogus

Given the [enumeration class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) with a private constructor, how can I configure **AutoBogus.AutoFaker**  to use my custom strategy when generating such a *class*?

In Example:

```cs
public class CardType
    : Enumeration
{
    public static CardType Amex = new(1, nameof(Amex));
    public static CardType Visa = new(2, nameof(Visa));
    public static CardType MasterCard = new(3, nameof(MasterCard));

    private CardType(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
    {
    }
}
```

I'd like to configure **AutoBogus.AutoFaker** in such way, that whenever it tries to generates a `CardType` it would use my code instead of not finding a public constructor and returning `null`.

I have tried `CardTypeFaker : AutoFaker<CardType>` but it only allows to configure Rules for properties of the class, not the instantiation of the class itsself.

I know I could create such an AutoFaker config for every class holding a `CardType` but that seems tedious.

Edit:

talking about [this library](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus) and specifically about the [AutoFaker](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus/blob/master/src/AutoBogus/AutoFaker.cs) part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured it out myself.

The global configuration does the work:

```cs
AutoFaker.Configure(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOverride(_ => new Faker().PickRandom(CardType.GetAll()));
});
```

I added the answer because the docs are not clear about and don't provide an example for this use case. As such someone might find it usefull.